# SAPUI5 web application launched from apple-touch-icon always in standalone mode

Tags: ios, safari, sapui5, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have added an icon for my SAPUI5 web app on the home screen of an iPhone. However it is displayed in standalone mode(full-screen) when launched from the icon even though I haven't added a

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

tag. Only if this tag has been added the app should be displayed in full screen mode(hiding the URL bar etc. of Safari). Even adding

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no">
```

doesn't help. As far as I have investigated it seems like this is an issue for apps built with UI5. For example [SAPUI5 DOCUMENTATION](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/) is also always displayed in full screen mode when launched from the home icon on iPhone. This is not the case for apps that are built without using UI5 and without the apple-mobile-web-app-capable tag.

Also when I comment out the part of my code that loads SAPUI5, the app is not launched in full screen mode.

Any suggestions how to display the app in non-standalone mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered after a lot of debugging that the sap.m.App control creates meta tags in index.html file. So the solution was to remove the meta tag that sap.m.App has created after the sap.m.App has been initialized.

Comment: Can you please tell how to `remove the meta tag that sap.m.App has created`? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, don't exactly remember since it was a long time ago, but I think I just used jQuery to remove the tag that causes the standalone mode